# Classification using GMM with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, mixture-model

I'm trying to classify a testset using GMM. I have a trainset (n*4 matrix) with labels {1,2,3}, n means the number of training examples, which have 4 properties. And I also have a testset (m*4) to be classified.

My goal is to have a probability matrix (m*3) for each testing example giving each label `P(x_test|labels)`. Just like soft clustering.

first, I create a GMM with k=9 components over the whole trainset. I know in some papers, the author create a GMM for each label in trainset. But I want to deal with the data from all of the classes.

```
    GMModel = fitgmdist(trainset,k_component,'RegularizationValue',0.1,'Start','plus');
```

My problem is, I want to confirm the relationship `P(component|labels)`between components and labels. So I write a code as below, but not sure if it's right,

```
    idx_ex_of_c1 = find(trainset_label==1);
    idx_ex_of_c2 = find(trainset_label==2);
    idx_ex_of_c3 = find(trainset_label==3);

    [~,~,post] = cluster(GMModel,trainset);
    cita_c_k = zeros(3,k_component);
    for id_k = 1:k_component
        cita_c_k(1,id_k) = sum(post(idx_ex_of_c1,id_k))/numel(idx_ex_of_c1);
        cita_c_k(2,id_k) = sum(post(idx_ex_of_c2,id_k))/numel(idx_ex_of_c2);
        cita_c_k(3,id_k) = sum(post(idx_ex_of_c3,id_k))/numel(idx_ex_of_c3);
    end
```

`cita_c_k` is a (3*9) matrix to store the relationships. `idx_ex_of_c1` is the index of examples, whose label is '1' in the trainset.

For the testing process. I first apply the GMModel to testset

```
    [P,~] = posterior(GMModel,testset); % P is a m*9 matrix
```

And then, sum all components,

```
    P_testset = P*cita_c_k';
    [a,b] = max(P_testset,3);
    imagesc(b);
```

The result is ok, But not good enough. Can anyone give me some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: why did you choose 9 components for your GMM? More is not necessarily better, in fact I've seen extremely complex training sets using only 5-7 components.

Comment: I'm not sure how many components can perform best. Maybe you are right. I'm going to find out the optimal #components.

Answer (score 0):

You can take following steps:

1. Increase *target error* and/or use optimal *network size* in training, but over-training and network size increase usually won't help
2. Most important, shuffle training data while training and use only important data points for a label to train (*ignore data points that may belong to more than one labels*)

**SEPARABILITY**

Verify separability of data using properties using correlation.

1. Correlation of all data in a label (X) should be high (near to one)
2. Cross-correlation of all data in label (X) with data in label (!=X) should be low (near zero).

If you observe that *data points in a label have low correlation* and *data points across labels have high correlation* - It puts a question on selection of properties (*there could be properties which actually won't make data separable*). Being so do follows:

1. Add more relevant properties to data points and remove less relevant properties (*technique to use this is PCA*)
2. Use *derived parameters* like *top frequency component* etc. from data points to train rather than direct points
3. Use a time delay network to train time series (always)